# How to copy part of a sprite I need to rotate in Pygame

Tags: rotation, sprite, crop

I have a sprite that is 180 wide by 90 high.  It shows 2 views of a rocket - one with engines firing and one with them not firing.  I need to be able to show just one view of the ship while also rotating it to any angle.  I can display the entire 180 x 90 sprite at any angle but can't figure out how to copy either the left hand or right hand image to a 90x90 rect before rotating and blitting it.  Here's my code.  ship_image is the 180x90 sprite with 2 ships in it, my transform.chop is meant to create a new 90x90 image of just one ship in ship3_image and the rest of the code rotates it and displays it (I have intentionally not cleared my display surface to show that my sprite really is rotating around its center).
So why do I not get a 90 x 90 sprite from the chop or what command do I use to get a 90 x 90 sprite?

Thanks for your help / ideas!
[screen shot of ships rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsxsS.jpg)

```
center=(200,200) #Store pos by center
angle = 0
while True:
    ship2_image = ship_image  #copy entire 2 ship image
    ship3_image = pygame.transform.chop(ship2_image,[0,0,90,90])#left hand image
    ship3_image=pygame.transform.rotate(ship_image,angle)  # Rotate whole image
    size=ship3_image.get_size() #Store size of rotated rect

    hSize=[n/2 for n in size] #Half the size
    pos=(center[0]-hSize[0]+200,center[1]-hSize[1])  #Subtract half the size
    #from the center
    frame.blit(ship3_image,pos) 
    angle += 1
    pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

```
ship2_image = ship_image.convert() # do this to all images to speed up processing
ship3_image=pygame.transform.scale(ship_image,(90,90)) # changes the size
```